# How do I remove an object inside a JSON object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question goes like this. I have a JSON object below. I want to remove the object that has an assignment 1. I already looped through it and by the best of me I cannot seem to remove that particular object.

```
0: Object
  teller_id: 1
  details: CASH
  assignments: Array [2]
   0: Object  <---- Remove this Object and all the elements indside it
      service_id: 1
      status: 1
      assignment: 1
   1: Object
      service_id: 1
      status: 1
      assignment: 2
1: Object
 teller_id: 2
 details: EMP
 assignments: Array [2]
   0: Object
      service_id: 2
      status: 3
      assignment: 4
   1: Object
      service_id: 2
      status: 4
      assignment: 6
```

Remove  object with an assignment of 1

```
0: Object
  teller_id: 1
  details: CASH
  assignments: Array [2]
   1: Object
      service_id: 1
      status: 1
      assignment: 2
1: Object
 teller_id: 2
 details: EMP
 assignments: Array [2]
   0: Object
      service_id: 2
      status: 3
      assignment: 4
   1: Object
      service_id: 2
      status: 4
      assignment: 6
```

In which it removes the Object[0] found inside the assignments array. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what how did you attempt to remove the required object? I mean the code that you wrote to carry this out?

Comment: delete myObject[0].assignments[0] ? N.B. the length of the array won't change if you do this as it will set the element to undefined

Comment: I've converted the previous comment to a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this really needs Angular, because it involves pure JavaScript.

In each object, `assignments` is an array. Whilst an array is a form of object, it has its own properties. There are a few ways to approach this.

Firstly if you wish to treat it as an array, then:

```
myObject[0].assignments.splice(0,1); // remove first element from array
```

or:

```
myObject[0].assignments.shift(); // get first element from array
```

This will however move the indexes of the assignments down in the array. i.e. assignments[1] will become assignments[0].

If you **don't** want to change the indices, then `delete` is what you're looking for:

```
delete myObject[0].assignments[0];
```

This will however cause the first element of the array to have the value `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks!! I got it running now

$scope.td[key].assignments.splice(key2,1); Where key is the index of the first object then key2 is the index of assignment_id.

Answer (score 0):

Let the variable name that points to the object is `ar`:

```
delete ar[0].assignments[0];
```

I hope you don't have trouble looping and finding the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice function for delete elements from array

```
var arr = [{name: 'Ram', assiignment: 1}, {name: 'Raju', assiignment: 2}];
arr.splice(0,1); // Here 0 is the index of element to be delete and 1 is how many elements to delete from that index we provided
```

After your array will like this:

```
[{name: 'Raju', assiignment: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
    for(var i = item.assignments.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        if (item.assignments[i].assignment === 1) {
            item.assignments.splice(i, 1);
        }
    } 
});
```

This is problematic with angular native.

If you are using some third party library like lodash or underscore, it will be easier.